# USB drive programming with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I am working on a project where I need to access some specific addresses of a USB drive (e.g. sector 0), and change some bytes. I have done some parts with C# already that includes user interface, detection of USB drives etc. Can anybody help me providing some links so that I can access specific addresses of USB drives with .NET?

Comment: C# has no I/O features. You'll have to use .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Framework doesn't support this. If you attempt to create a FileStream on a device it will throw an exception. You will have to use the Windows API methods directly (p/invoke CreateFile, DeviceIoControl, etc). Make sure you read the section on Physical Disks and Volumes here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx

Comment: please don't post old links. Don't post MSDN links that have version numbers in them, unless you're actually _trying_ to provide old information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not privy to MSDNs URL naming convention. That link looks current from my view.

Comment: Ah, I see it was the (v=VS.85) in the link. I'll try to pay attention in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can i call this from my c# code? Can you provide any link that shows C# with win API?

Comment: Tutorial on p/invoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx. CreateFile @ pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateFile.html. Pinvoke.net is a 'fair' place to lookup API signatures for C# (and VB). I say 'fair' because there is some incorrect info there (not a lot), and also because with p/invoke, there isn't always just one answer. You can write p/invoke declarations a number of ways, but doing so on your own requires some understanding of how the marshaller works.